# "Order status vs status on my order" and other similar expressions

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

What's the difference between a) city landscape and the landscape of a city b) passport copy and copy of my passport c) order status and status of my order?

Are all they grammatically and meaning-wise correct in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are all equally good.  English is a bit unusual, compared to many European languages, of not as frequently using 'of' for possession or relation.  For example, in German it would be more common to see what would literally be 'the mother of the wife of my brother', whereas English is OK with 'my brother's wife's mother', and uses the genitive/possessive case more than many languages.

I don't know the exact grammatical term, but English is also OK using what look like nouns as a sort of adjective.  In your example, 'city landscape' (as opposed to 'abstract landscape' or 'beautiful landscape') fits that pattern.

The typical example of where this seems grammatically to beg for an answer is when people say things like 'boys hockey', 'mens room', or 'girls lacrosse' without an apostrophe to indicate possession - even though in one of these 'men' is clearly already plural.  I have heard it claimed - but cannot verify - that it may trace to an archaic form of the dative case which has since disappeared in English.